# How to scrape the links hidden in the dropdown menu using scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am going to scrape NFL depth charts from web pages, e.g. https://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/archive/220/BUF . Now I want to get all the links to this kind of pages, but the source code of the dropdown menu "Archive Dates" does not include any links:

```html
    <option value="">-- Archive Dates --</option>
    <option value="220">05/01/2019</option>
    <option value="219">04/01/2019</option>
    <option value="218">03/01/2019</option>
    <option value="217">02/01/2019</option>
    <option value="216">01/01/2019</option>
    <option value="215">12/01/2018</option>
    <option value="214">11/01/2018</option>
    <option value="213">10/01/2018</option>
    <option value="212">09/01/2018</option>
    <option value="211">08/01/2018</option>
```

I read a post [Web scrape get drop-down menu data python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091598/web-scrape-get-drop-down-menu-data-python) , which I think is helpful since he indicated that the web page uses JavaScript.

But that answer uses selenium. I wonder if I can solve the problem using scrapy or beautifulsoup.

The following is the structure of my scraper.

```py
class depth_chart_archive_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "depth_chart_archive"
    start_urls = ('https://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/',)

    def parse(self, response):
        dchome = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')

        # get the links somehow

        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse_team)

    def parse_team(self, response):
        # parse the page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the URL using the `value` parameter found on each `option` tag.

For example, the menu that refer to 05/01/2019 has `value=220` in the `option` tag

```
<option value="220">05/01/2019</option>
```

The url opened when you click on this menu is:

```
https://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/archive/220/BUF
```

So it follows a pattern, you can request all items using something like:

```
site_url = 'https://www.ourlads.com/nfldepthcharts/archive/{code}/BUF'

for code in response.xpath('//option/@value').re(r'\d+'):
    yield Request(site_url.format(code=code))
```

The regex is only to avoid requesting the first item `<option value="">-- Archive Dates --</option>`